# How can I search molecules by constituent atoms

Tags: atoms, molecules, cheminformatics

Given a set of atoms, I would like to find (some / the most common) molecules that include only (some/all) atoms of the set. Is there any online search engine that can do this?

> E.g.
>   Atoms={C,H}
>   -->
>   Molecules={CH$_4$, C$_2$H$_6$, ...}

Note:

- I am looking for known molecules.
- It is OK if I can only find chemical formulae, so without all possible configurations.

Comment: Personally, I doubt so because there are literally millions, if not billions, of compounds that contain C and H (or any combination of atoms that you specify, unless it's something esoteric like Zr, N, Se).

Comment: Is there some database where you could enter a formula like $C_aH_bO_c$ and get molecules ( compounds) that fit (where a,b and c are given integers)? Certainly by the time that you get to 100 carbons there are more unknown possible compounds than known ones.

Comment: Pft, you can even check Wikipedia for compounds containing specific elements.

Comment: You can search ChemSpider using a formula for one... http://www.chemspider.com/Search.aspx?rid=40b3a5ef-3142-406c-bbb0-c05e69d10a6e

Comment: I'm pretty certain the question here is about searching *known* molecules, not theoretical ones. There are millions of connected chemical-like graphs with formula N3O4P5 yet I doubt very much that many of them correspond to stable chemical structures!

Comment: @gilleain - Yes, I am looking for known molecules.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ChemSpider's full search:

http://www.chemspider.com/FullSearch.aspx

and click on the 'Elements' section. Alternatively, there is a direct link here:

http://www.chemspider.com/ElementsSearch.aspx

This gives you two periodic tables that you can select elements from for your search. I think the upper one is 'allowed' and the lower one is 'forbidden', but I haven't tested this.

Of course, as pointed out in the comments, the set {C, H} will give you most of the database! However, for rarer elements this can be a better filter.